# What would be an example of "Reading unbounded stream from standard input (Memory Management)"

Tags: c++, security

What would be an example of "Reading unbounded stream from standard input (Memory Management)" There is code in a sample project that represent the statement but I'm not sure what this statement means. Please give me an example of this in terms of code. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's imagine I have a speach-to-text program set up, so it has access to my microphone and the text generated is getting sent to stdout. If I pipe that program into your program, then I can just keep talking as long as I want. I can even take a break and go find my Lord Of The Rings trilogy. Your program will never get an EOF (end-of-file) signal (typically `-1`). Sometimes it will hang waiting for more input, and other times it will just get more and more text. There's no end (bound) to the input (stdin) stream.

An even easier example would be reading from `/dev/urandom`, although that wouldn't be obvious if you're not used to working with streams in this way.